# React Native Android simulator console.error: "error:",{}

Tags: android, react-native

The application was working completely fine last night. Made zero changes.

Today when I run `react-native run-android`, I can't get the application to start on the android simulator. I get the following:

[image: android emulator error]

Not sure where to begin troubleshooting.

Running react-native 0.54.4 on Mac OS 10.13.3. I don't see any syntax errors in any of my application code.

Comment: cd to android folder and run `gradlew clean` then `cd ..` and try running, also check if your console logs are syntactically correct.

Comment: @JudeFernandesI should mention I did run `gradlew clean`, still, the same results.

Comment: Is it possible to see some code?

Comment: @JudeFernandes I wouldn't be sure where to start, it's a fairly large application.

Comment: Goto your index.js file or whatever your app entry point is and comment out all components in the render and just display an empty <View /> tag, see if app works, if it does then continue with adding the component one at a time, tedious task but no other way

Comment: I stripped down my entry point to a hello world example, same issue. Is there anyway to clean out any caches/dependecies and have them rebuilt?

Comment: in the android folder you will have a build folder, delete that. In your home folder there will be a folder/file called rncache delete that

Comment: In the AVD, I went to my Emulator -> Wipe Data. Stuff works again. Should I put that down as the answer and mark it as right?

Comment: Try clear cache.    1) Kill metro bundler by `killall node`
2) Uninstall the app from emulator
3) `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`

Comment: @randombits You can put down all the things that were suggested to you as the answer so people can try all of them and hopefully one works.